# How to avoid writing the same blocks multipe times | MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

In my app I have 50 Horizontal Arrangements. (named row1, row2, row3 etc)

The user enters a number between 1-50 in a text field.

Based on this number,  the corresponding Horizontal Arrangement is altered (e.g: the user enters 28, so do something to row28).

Rather than write blocks to handle every 1-50 scenario (they are all the same, just the name would have to change), is there a way to take the user input and go to that row? Something like:

-user enters 28, so set row[28] to visible

...so [] would be a placeholder listening for whatever number is entered by the user.

Is this possible?  It seems as though you have to select each specific row (e.g row42) when you are building the blocks, rather than have a generic code block (e.g row) with a placeholder which can add the number (e.g 42) in as the app runs.

Comment: When you were learning about App Inventor did you see: [Procedures](https://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/concepts/procedures)?

Comment: Thanks Morrison. If I use a procedure that has userInput as an argument, I still can't see how to use that argument to set a components name to alter that component. I know it has to be something like "set row[argument] to visible", but I can't see how to insert a blank row component that preceeds [argument].  Any tips?

Comment: Sorry I don't know AppInventor (but know a bunch of other computer languages). You might have luck if you [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58810456/edit) your question with more detail about what you are doing and perhaps with code (or images of it). Sadly the problem with graphical programming is the lack of conciseness with written communication. Searching around perhaps this will help: https://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/blogs/karen/2016/07-0.html

Comment: use the advanced blocks, see also [How to work with the advanced features](https://puravidaapps.com/checkbox.php)... however first you might want to describe, why you think you need 50 horizontal arrangements (as you said, they are all the same)... Follow the DRY principle - Don't repeat yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the below thread to reduce the number of blocks as well as to learn some best practices while coding with blocks in App Inventor. :)
https://community.kodular.io/t/using-blocks-in-another-way/15752?u=shreyash